# Restrict node to be shown only in a view and not by its url?

Tags: views, nodes

I created a node which has an entity reference to select a user. Then, I created a view to show the node only to the user referenced in the node.

This works fine, but the problem is that the node can be viewed directly through its URL. I need to restrict the node to be only shown through the view and not by its URL.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module is exactly that, even if it doesn't apply just in the view case.

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.

The module has a version for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8, although the later is still a beta version, on December, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module. It provides access permissions to users referenced from nodes.

From the project page:

> Gives content access permissions to users for content that references the users with User reference or Entity reference.
>   This is great if you want your content authors to be able to choose additional authors, or choose who can view their content, as well as being able to display the list of authors or viewers within your content, or in views displays.

Regarding the redirect itself - try using `hook_init()` or `hook_page_alter()`, checking the node type and then redirecting to appropriate page. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338816/1678407) answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of the following:

- create redirect rule to redirect from node page to view page (Redirect module),
- use Rules module to create a rule (when user is showing specific content, show permission denied page),
- create `hook_menu` and page callback to refuse access on specific criteria,
- hide fields on for node Display or use Field Permissions module to restrict access to specific fields

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating Kenorb answer you can simply implement hook_menu_alter to change page_callback or access callback for node urls something like below.

```
mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = '_mymodule_my_content_type_redirection_rule';
}

/**
 * Page Callback for node/view page
 */
function _mymodule_my_content_type_redirection_rule($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
    drupal_goto('view_path');
  }
  else {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}
```

or if you want user to redirect to page not found you can do something like

```
mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = '_mymodule_my_content_type_redirection_rule';
}

/**
 * Page Callback for node/view page
 */
function _mymodule_my_content_type_redirection_rule($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
    return(drupal_not_found());
  }
  else {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}
```

If you want to block the access for the node page

```
mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = '_mymodule_node_access_rule';
}

/**
 * Access Callback for node/view page.
 */
function _mymodule_node_access_rule($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```