# Display node in view only

Tags: 8

I've created a views slideshow which uses a custom content type for each slide.
However I want to prevent any user to access these nodes using the url itself like `.../node/1`.
There seems to be a [module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145841/restrict-node-to-be-shown-only-in-a-view-and-not-by-its-url) from another stackoverflow post, but it's not supported by drupal 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the Rabbit Hole module for this.

https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

You can block the view route for nodes by content type.